# How do you know if a mouse has stopped hovering over an element?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to know how mouse has stopped hovering over an element in javascript or using css.
I am making an animation, that the background changes colour when it is being hovered by a mouse and I also want to add animation when mouse stopped hovering over an element. How can I do that?

Comment: listen for the [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) event

Comment: [Element: mouseout event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event)

Answer (score 1):

The background change will automatically revert when the mouse no longer hovers over the element:

```css
div:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div>Hover to turn yellow</div>
```

So there is no need for you to listen to an event, CSS will automatically detect that.

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: "I also want to add animation when mouse stopped hovering over an element" so, JS is the way to go.

Comment: @F.Müller Not necesseraly, you can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74938732/17684809) that only use css and has a transition when you start and stop hovering an element

Answer (score 1):

You need to check mouseout event.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event

Answer (score 1):

`onmouseover` and `onmouseout` JavaScript events help you to make animation on hover and out

```js
function onDiv(x) {
//on div
  x.style.background = "#f00";
 
}

function outsideDiv(x) {
//out side div
  x.style.background = "#000";
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="onDiv(this)" onmouseout="outsideDiv(this)" style='border:2px solid #000;width:100px;height:100px;'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `transition` to your element (and not to the element:hover or you will get the transition only on hover, not on mouseout).

```css
.square {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: background-color .5s linear;
}

.square:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```